# AWK script to Substring on tab delmited line

Tags: awk, gawk

I am trying to do awk script to one of my project. I stuck at the below scenario,

**Persons.txt** (Tab delimited file)

```
A   M   DHANABALAN  INDIA ....
B   F   SUBHA   US
```

I want to replace second tab **M** with **Male** and **F** with **Female** and keep all other tab value as such.

**Expected output**

```
A   Male    DHANABALAN  INDIA ....
B   Female  SUBHA   US
```

I am trying as below

**My code**

```
{ 
    if( $2 == "M"){
        print $1 "Male" 
    }else{
        print $1 "Female"
    }
}
```

Don't know how to print the remaining tabs. Pleas assist me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ 
    if($2=="M"){
        $2="Male" 
    }
    else{
        $2="Female"
    }
    {print}
}' file
```

or

```
$ awk '{$2=="M"?$2="Male":$2="Female"}1' file
```

### Output :

```
A Male DHANABALAN INDIA ....
B Female SUBHA US
```

Comment: Thank you. Its works fine for sample. I will try to implement the same in actual scenario and update you. Thanks again